# Glossaries long form with hyper-ref

Tags: glossaries

I can use `\glsentrylong` to use the long form. But this does not generate a hyper-ref to the section in the glossaries section.

How can I use the long form with hyper-ref? Like `\gls` would do.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym[
description={\Glsentrylong{nn}. Statistical model.}
]{nn}{NN}{neural network}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\Gls{nn}.  % this has a hyperref. and also is backlinked in glossaries later.

\Gls{nn}.  % this as well

\Glsentrylong{nn}.  % this does not have a hyperref

\printglossary[title={Glossary}]

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry but you are really long enough here to know that minimal examples are needed.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Also in such cases where it would not add any further information like here?

Comment: Yes. I at least won't write a test document from scratch to understand the problem and check if a solution works. So if you don't provide a small complete example I won't bother with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using acronyms, and there you get the long form with \Acrlong:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\newacronym[
description={\Glsentrylong{nn}. Statistical model.}
]{nn}{NN}{neural network}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}

\Gls{nn}.  % this has a hyperref. and also is backlinked in glossaries later.

\Gls{nn}.  % this as well

\Glsentrylong{nn}.  % this does not have a hyperref

\Acrlong{nn}

\printglossary[title={Glossary}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A small extension to my original question: Can I also replace the text, e.g. "neural model", but it still links to the acronym "neural network", and also gets a backlink?